# "Rails server" creates a new app called "server" not start the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've transferred an older RoR app onto a new workstation and now having issues starting it.

For instance when I attempt to use the "rails server" command it generates a new rails application rather than starting the server.

I did have it running last night but after attempting to use the 'Production' database, apparently the 'rails server -e "production" ' command is obsolete.  I therefore tried:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
```

And it seems the application was not longer working.

There was also lots of documentation and suggestions to use RVM....which I installed....could that be the cause the 'rails server' command is not starting the server but rather creating a new app?

Comment: Are you actually in your Rails application directory when you try to start the server?

Comment: Yes...the application directory...not the 'app' directory in the application directory.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?  If it's Rails 2 you would need `script/server` to start the server rather than `rails server`.

Comment: 'script/server' not working.... how can I confirm what version I have?  'bundle list' or 'gem list'?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `ruby script/server`

Comment: To start the server I had to use: `bundle exec rails server` what's going on?

Comment: Using `bundle exec` will ensure it uses the version of rails from your  Gemfile.  This is default behaviour after Rails 3.1 but your app is older than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start the server I had to use: bundle exec rails server what's going on? –  paulywill yesterday

Using bundle exec will ensure it uses the version of rails from your Gemfile. This is default behaviour after Rails 3.1 but your app is older than that. –  Graeme McLean yesterday

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

on rails app dir.

I think your app is on rails 3, with rails 4 installed.

Comment: try rails -v also bundle install on that dir where app is.

Comment: 'Rails 2.3.14'
 bundle install
Using rails (3.2.9)

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` this created another app in a directory called `s`

Comment: share gem file also tell us what ruby you are using. its definitely version problem